# ResultSet is reused

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, resultset

Okay so I have a piece of code that is called several time. However during some testing I noticed that my ResultSet is returning wrong according to the database. After further investigations I noticed that it is somehow is reused. WORTH mentioning is that when I restart the program, it fetches the right result. The SQL is always the same.

My code:

```
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setInt(1, packet.getUserId());
ResultSet dbResult = ps.executeQuery();

while(dbResult.next())
{
    System.out.println("There were items!" );
    Item item = new Item();
    item.setItemType(dbResult.getInt(1));
    item.setFromUser(dbResult.getString(2));
    item.setItemMessage(dbResult.getString(3));
    toReturn.add(item);
}
```

This has been my testing sequence:

- Get rows from ResultSet once and get right results - OK
- Delete all rows from the table that the particular sql above uses, meaning that the ResultSet should return nothing next time.
- Try fetching again (now it should return 0 rows) BUT it returns the exact same rows as in step 1, even though the database table is empty.

Should the ResultSet be closed or something after use, or what am I missing?
I get results from the ResultSet even though there is nothing in the database. I can guarantee that the SQL is legit, but the ResultSet does'nt seem to be created from it the 2nd time it's called.

EDIT (Connection initialization code)

```
public class DBFactory 
{
    protected String databaseName = null;
    protected String username = null;
    protected String password = null;
    protected Connection connection = null;
    protected Statement statement = null;

    protected DBFactory( String databaseName, String username, String password)
    {
        this.databaseName = databaseName;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    protected void initConnection()
    {
        if (databaseName == null || username == null || password == null)
            throw new IllegalStateException();

        try 
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            this.connection = DriverManager.getConnection(this.databaseName, this.username, this.password);
            this.statement = this.connection.createStatement();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            System.out.println("DBFactory " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: You've left out the important bits of your code, showing HOW you delete the rows and reissue the query, and the options on your connection (REPEATABLE_READ, etc).  Without those details we're just guessing.

Comment: I don't delete them from code, I do that manually outside the program.

Comment: Post the code that creates the connection.

Comment: But does your code terminate and then restart after you perform the external changes, or does it continue running somehow and reissue the query?

Comment: This code is located serverside, meaning each time a client calls for this information, this code is runned (The function at the top)

Comment: WORTH mentioning is that when I restart the program, it fetches the right result again..

Comment: `System.out.println("There were items!" );` is that line executed when you empty your tables and run without restarting?

Comment: Yes it is. I have done some more investigation on the subject and it seems that PreparedStatements uses caching. Since I run the same sql several times, it uses the cached one. However they are supposed to become invalid when a table changes, but that doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: I don't create a new connection each time, i'm using the same. Maybe that should be changed?

Comment: Are you somehow inside a transaction?  What comes between the DBFactory and the query code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I expect you have auto commit turned off for the connection.

As far as I can understand your problem, this small code example will demonstrate it.

```
package org.yi.happy.mysql;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class RepeatQuery {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

        setupDatabase();

        System.out.println("opening database...");
        Connection connection = openConnection();
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);

        queryDatabase(connection);

        deleteRecords();

        queryDatabase(connection);

        connection.close();
    }

    private static Connection openConnection() throws SQLException {
        return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test", null,
                null);
    }

    private static void setupDatabase() throws SQLException {
        Connection conn = openConnection();

        System.out.println("doing insert on another connection...");
        PreparedStatement stmt = conn
                .prepareStatement("insert into strings(id, value) values(?, ?)");

        stmt.setInt(1, 1);
        stmt.setString(2, "test");
        stmt.execute();

        stmt.setInt(1, 2);
        stmt.setString(2, "data");
        stmt.execute();

        stmt.close();
        conn.close();
    }

    private static void deleteRecords() throws SQLException {
        Connection conn = openConnection();
        System.out.println("doing delete on another connection...");
        PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("delete from strings");
        stmt.execute();

        stmt.close();
        conn.close();
    }

    private static void queryDatabase(Connection connection)
            throws SQLException {
        System.out.println("doing query...");
        PreparedStatement ps = connection
                .prepareStatement("select id, value from strings");
        ResultSet dbResult = ps.executeQuery();

        while (dbResult.next()) {
            int id = dbResult.getInt(1);
            String value = dbResult.getString(2);
            System.out.println(id + " <=> " + value);
        }
    }
}
```

The output of the above is

```
doing insert on another connection...
opening database...
doing query...
2 <=> data
1 <=> test
doing delete on another connection...
doing query...
2 <=> data
1 <=> test
```

If I change

```
            connection.setAutoCommit(false);
```

to read

```
            connection.setAutoCommit(true);
```

the output becomes

```
doing insert on another connection...
opening database...
doing query...
2 <=> data
1 <=> test
doing delete on another connection...
doing query...
```

which is what you appear to expect.

Answer (score 0):

You are likely in a transaction, if you commit or rollback the current transaction you will see the current state of the database.

Try a

```
        connection.rollback();
```

or

```
        connection.commit();
```

before your query, or turn on auto commit.